# Ajax form validation in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Ajax form that I need to hit a JavaScript function on failure, like so:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateStages", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "refreshSearchResults('" + @Model.First().ItemCode + "')",
    OnFailure = "showError"
}))
```

With the `showError` function taking the Ajax context response and appending it to a `div`, like so:

```
function showError(ajaxContext) 
{
    var response = ajaxContext.responseText;
    response = $($.trim(response));
    var itemVersion = response.filter("div")[0].innerHTML.trim().toString();
    var error = response.filter("p")[0].outerHTML.toString();
    $("#" + itemVersion.replace(".", "") + "-UpdateStagesResults").empty();
    $(error).appendTo("#" + itemVersion.replace(".", "") + "-UpdateStagesResults");
}
```

In order for the `OnFailure` to be called I have in my MVC controller `ActionResult`, when an error occurs:

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
return PartialView();
```

which returns a `PartialView` with the error message in the `ViewBag`. This works fine when running locally, the error message is sent to the `showError` function and then the error is appended to the page.

The problem is that when I put the application onto a live server (IIS7), the Ajax context is just

> Bad Request

and for example is not:

```
<p>You have not entered a valid date.</p>
<div style="display:none;">V7.0  </div>
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this,

in IIS7 the default error settings are to show detailed error messages locally only., your view is replaced with the default for the status code.

If you want to see your custom errors, add this into your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```

that should sort it

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this! I had tried changing the custom error settings but that didn't work.